# Using the wallet RPC method create_wallet, how do we find our wallet address?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

Using the method [create_wallet](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_wallet), gives a blank result json object (`result:{}`), so how do we get the newly created wallet address and related key for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response from a call to [create_wallet](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_wallet) has an empty result object, no error object and has HTTP status code of 200, the wallet has been successfully created and opened.

You can then simply call the wallet RPC method [get_address](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_address) to obtain the wallet address.

Comment: Ok, understood. So the result object has first parameter of an address, this is my wallet address, if I am getting this, right? and rest of the addresses which are included by addresses array, those are the sub address of that particular wallet.

Comment: The result object for `get_address` has two members, `address`, which is the main address, and `addresses`, an array of address information. There are examples in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When starting `monero-wallet-rpc` you specify a `--wallet-dir`.
When calling rpc method "create_wallet" which would create a new wallet, you have to specify a `filename` and a `password`:

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:18082/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"create_wallet","params":{"filename":"mytestwallet","password":"mytestpassword","language":"English"}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Take `filename` and `password` and proceed to [get_address](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_address)

Comment: So, here wallet address need to have an account? Because request parameters for get_address method requires account_index to call that method.

Comment: When creating a wallet, there will be a default/account/main address at index 0. That's your `public address`. From there you can create `subaddress` or `account`, and `subaddress` for that new account.